# Limit the number of times an AJAX Request on Keyup fires

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've build a HTML input field that is linked to a PHP script. When a username is input into the field, it searches for usernames from the database without page refresh with the help of the jQuery / AJAX below.

**My issue:**
The code works, however when I input a letter it fires a hell of a lot of XHR requests off in the console. Is there a way to limit how many times the AJAX POST requests are fired off over a period of time, if so, how would I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').keyup(function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"guild_find.php",
        data:{username:username},
        success:function(res){
        $('#userslist').html(res);

        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Search for "debouncing".

Comment: Just had a look, that seems like a decent solution. How would I go about applying the method to the above code?

Answer (score 4):

You want to wrap your keyup function with a so called `debounce`. This is similar to an event throttle, but will ensure that the AJAX request will be called after the last keyup is performed.

jQuery has a built in throttle/debounce. If you want your request to be called at most every 200 ms, you can write:

```
$("#username").keyup(debounce(ajaxRequestFn, 200);
```

where `ajaxRequestFn` is the function that performs the request, and the `debounce` implementation is for instance:

```
// func       callback function
// wait       throttle time in ms
// immediate  bool, should callback be called on first event
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function () {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

use a timeout and clear it in each keyup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myTimeout;
    $('#username').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimeout);
        var username = $('#username').val();
        myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"guild_find.php",
                data:{username:username},
                success:function(res){
                    $('#userslist').html(res);  
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's still firing off a hell of a lot of requests, they're just delayed. I've just quickly searched Barmar's suggestion and am trying to figure out how to apply it. This url pretty much speaks my problem with the input box:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Comment: check my edit. I've had the variable in the wrong place.